# How do I write an element of a quotient of a set of vectors by matrix in $GL_2(\Bbb Q)$?

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology, quotient-group

My first time writing the quotient of a set of vectors by a matrix.  Let the set of vectors $X=\pmatrix{x\\1}$ have $x\in\Bbb Q_2$ drawn from the 2-adic numbers.

Now let the matrices of the form $G=\pmatrix{2^\mathbb Z & \mathbb Z[\frac12]\\0&1}$ represent a group action $G$ expressed by the map:

$(t,u) \mapsto \pmatrix{2^u & t\\0&1}$

**Question**

How do I write the quotient of $X$ by the group action of $G$?

And how do I identify some element of:

- $G$
- $X/G$?

**My Attempt (using $-\frac13$ as an example)**

I guess the quotient is written as simply as $X/G$

I think an element of $G$ is simply written $\pmatrix{1&-\frac13\\0&1}$ *Note

An element of $X/G$ I'm not so sure about.  Let's take for example the element $\pmatrix{\Bbb Z[\frac12]-\frac132^\Bbb Z\\1}$.  I think that's the best notation for that, that I can suggest just now.  Any improvements would be appreciated.

I guess something writing it as a single representative would be more elegant, like $G\pmatrix{-\frac13\\1}$

Or maybe $\pmatrix{2^\mathbb Z & \mathbb Z[\frac12]\\0&1}\times\pmatrix{-\frac13\\1}$

*Note:  I'm aware $-\frac13$ isn't an element of the group. One must specify the power of 2 to which one is multiplying $x$ as well as the addor, in this case I've used $2^0$

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to describe the orbit of a vector under the (cyclic) subgroup generated by the matrix.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven sounds reasonable although I don't fully follow.  The function $T$ given in the other question I asked today here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513710/ describes the orbit of $G$ in THIS question through $\pmatrix{\Bbb Q_2\\1}$. Are you referring to the orbit of the function $T$? Are you calling $G$ the cyclic subgroup, and not $X/G$?  If I understand correctly, $X/G$ would be a bit like $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$

Comment: @DavidA.Craven if you're saying $G$ describes what you said then yes, I think I agree.  In which case I'm trying to get a clear way of representing or notating $X/G$

Comment: I'm saying that one does not take quotients of elements by groups. What it seems like you want is that you have a group $G$ acting on the set $\Omega$ of all vectors $v$, and you want to know all vectors in the orbit $\{gv\mid g\in G\}$. Your terminology is a bit wonky, so it's unclear what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven it's the terminology I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing out I wrote quotient of an element, I'll fix. I want quotient of the set $X$ and $X$ is same as your $\Omega$.

Comment: The orbit space is the set of all orbits. Quotient usually refers to when one takes two objects of the same type, one inside the other, and considers a homomorphism with kernel the subset, e.g., a vector space and a subspace.

Comment: Thanks @DavidA.Craven in this case the quotient of a space by a group action is I think tentatively a quotient of the group of automorphisms of the space, whatever that means.

Comment: It is the quotient, or in geometric settings such as what you have, the orbit space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: ok thanks for your help @DavidA.Craven I'll have a closer look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient of a set $X$ by a group action $G$ is commonly written $X/G$.

$X/G$ is the orbit space of the group action $G$ in the set $X$ and comprises the set of all orbits. If there's precisely one orbit, the group acts transitively on $X$.

In the example given above, the orbit through $\pmatrix{-\frac13\\1}$ can be written $G\cdot\pmatrix{-\frac13\\1}=\left\{g\cdot\pmatrix{-\frac13\\1}:g\in G\right\}$.